# How to find text from populated model in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

We have two models:

1. User

```
   const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       name: {
           type: String
       },
       email: {
           type: String
       },
       vehicleId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'vehicle'
       }
   })
```

2. Vehicle

```
    const vehicleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       name: {
           type: String
       },
       color: {
           type: String
       }
   })
```

Now, we have to find user input from user's ( name, email ) & also from vehicle's ( name, color )

```
- If user search "pink" then we have to find that if any user has with name, email or them vehicle include "pink" keyword or not.
- If string match from reference model then we have to return whole record.
```

Can you please help us, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the best thing you can do is, [Text Search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation).

ANSWER 1:

1.1. Step one

You have to create text index on your collection to perform text search.

create text index with

```
db.user.createIndex({"name":"text", "email": "text"})

db.vehicle.createIndex({"name": "text", "color": "text"})
```

we have to create text index on both collection as we want to perform **text search** on both collections.

*
**Note:**

> as we are creating a text index on "name", "email" from User & "name", "color" from Vehicle, you can only perform text search on this four fields in respective collections.
>
> you can assign weights to fields so that you can sort your result according to text score. (you must do this while creating index).

*

1.2. Step two

*(i am assuming you are using Javascript and mongoose here.)*

```
 db.collection("users").aggregate({$match:{$text: {$search: "pink"}}},
         (err, userData: any)=>{
            if(err){
                return err;
            }

    if(userdata.length){

            let vehicleIds = userData.map((user) => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user.vehicleId));

            db.collection("vehicles").aggregate({$match:{$text:{$search:"pink", _id: {$in: vehicleIds}}}}, (err, vehicleData)=>{

                     //this will be your vehicle details
            })
        })

   }else{
       console.log("no Data found");
   }
```

*

> **The problem** with this approach is you have to fire two queries because of the [restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/#restrictions) in **Text Search** and extra overhead of text index on collections.
>
> **Good Thing** is you get a lot of ways to perform a search, you can sort results according to relevance with **text score**, it is fast than the regular expression and you get better results, you get stemming, you get stop words (please ref links that are given).
>   *

---

ANSWER 2:

you can use regular expression

```
db.collection("users").aggregate({$match:{$or:[{name:{$regex: /pink/}}, {email:{$regex: /pink/}}]}},

    {$lookup:{from:"vehicles", localField:"vehicleId", foreignFild:"_id", as:"vehicleDetail"}},

    {$unwind:{path:"$vehicleDetail"}},

    {$match:{$or:[{name:{$regex:/pink/}},{color:{$regex:/pink/}}]}}

    (err, data)=>{

    })
```

ANSWER 3:

If you dont want to prefer above options, you can fire normal query too

db.collection("users").aggregate({$match:{$or:[{name:{$regex: /pink/}}, {email:{$regex: /pink/}}]}},

```
    {$lookup:{from:"vehicles", localField:"vehicleId", foreignFild:"_id", as:"vehicleDetail"}},

    {$unwind:{path:"$vehicleDetail"}},

    {$match:{$or:[{name:{$regex:/pink/}},{color:{$regex:/pink/}}]}}

    (err, data)=>{

    })
```

Hope this helps. :-)
Correct me if I am wrong anywhere. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can first run a query on a Vehicle model to fetch all vehicles that have name pink

```
let vehicleIds=await Model.Vehicle.aggregate([
 {$match:{$or:[
             {name:{$regex:"pink",$options:"i"}},
             {color:{$regex:"pink",$options:"i"}
 ]}},
 {$group:{_id:null,ids:{$push:"$_id"}}}    
])
```

here if vehicleIds is not empty, then vehicles[0].ids will have vehcileIds that have pink in name or color

```
let vehcileIds=[]
if(vehicles.length) vehcileIds=vehicles[0].ids
```

after above query runs run another query in the user model

```
let users= await Models.User.find({$or:[
{name:{$regex:"pink",$options:"i"}},
{email:{$regex:"pink",$options:"i"}
{vehicleId:{$in:}}
]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Below steps you should follow:

- Find user by name and email.
- Populate vehicle
- Again match with the color.

---

```
db.getCollection('User').aggregate([
  { $match: { email: "h@gmail.com", name: "Hardik"}},
  { $lookup: {from: 'Vehicle', localField: 'vehicleId', foreignField: '_id', as: 'vehicle'} },
  { $match: { "vehicle.color": {$regex: '.*'+ "Pink" +'.*', $options: 'si'}}},
])
```

**Data:**

**User**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d51bd5ef5fc3d6486b40ffb"),
    "email" : "h@gmail.com",
    "name" : "Hardik",
    "vehicleId" : ObjectId("5d539786f5fc3d6486b4252b")
}
```

**Vehicle**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d539786f5fc3d6486b4252b"),
    "name" : "Bike",
    "color" : "Pink"
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d51bd5ef5fc3d6486b40ffb"),
    "email" : "h@gmail.com",
    "name" : "Hardik",
    "vehicleId" : ObjectId("5d539786f5fc3d6486b4252b"),
    "vehicle" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d539786f5fc3d6486b4252b"),
            "name" : "Bike",
            "color" : "Pink"
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps!